# Как оптимизировать показ сообщение PHP

Tags: php

У пользователя есть страница сообщения, где он видит сообщения от других пользователей, а так же показано сколько непрочитанных сообщений от каждого пользователей, Как оптимизировать запросы к базе при загрузки пользователем страницы сообщений? Сейчас каждый диалог проверяется циклом и считает сообщения и показывает прочитаны они или нет вследствии чего на странице очень много запросов. Подскажите как решать подобную проблему. Структура таблицы http://prntscr.com/fbp9e2 .

Comment: А структуру таблиц[ы] показать? (create statement)

Comment: Получить все непрочитанные, а на рнр их отсортировать по непрочитанным от каждого юзера

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в самой таблице завести поле Прочитано/Непрочитано, и помечать, что сообщение прочитано.